# I want a fixed result of cookies, but I can't get it

Tags: php, .htaccess, cookies

I have a problem with this simple thing but it makes me very confuse. I have done a "clear browsing data from the begining". I just want a constant result but I can't get it. I already have a result but after i press F5 button (refresh) several times, that result sometimes changed by itself (inconstantly). Cooval means "cookies value" and I just want that cooval's result is constant. The result are between only 2 of choises, that are "eagle" and "royaken".

There are three things that I confused:

1. I just try only one url that is "*******.com/home" in the address bar. The logic is
   certainly goes into the condition 1 and never goes to the condition 2,
   because the url is ******/home, but why does the result inconstant?
   sometimes "eagle" and sometimes "royaken".
2. If the logic goes into the condition 2, then the alert and echo should be
   shown up, but it's not, it assumes that the logic is never
   goes to the condition 2, but there's one rand() code is in the
   condition 2 that might be the caused.
3. If I used this sign /* blablabla */ for the entire of the condition 2 like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4PRt.jpg),
   then the result is totally fixed, but then it's weird, while it shouldn't be entering to the condition 2 and also i have use "exit;" on the
   condition 1 so it's imposible if the logic goes to the condition 2.

the image:
[image]

Index.php

```
<?php
    $hostname='localhost';
    $database='*********';
    $username='*********';
    $password='*********';
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);

    session_start();
    ob_start();
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Jakarta");
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);  

    $urlget = $_GET['url'];
    $urlexplode = filter_var($urlget, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $url = explode("/", $urlexplode);   
    $urlsave=$url[0];
    echo "urlsave=$urlsave<br>";

    if($urlsave=='home'){
        //----------------------------------------condition 1
        $coousername='myCookie';
        $cooval=$_COOKIE[$coousername];
        echo "cooval=$cooval<br>";
        exit;
    }else{
        //----------------------------------------condition 2
        echo "<script language=javascript> alert('I am in the condition 2')</script>"; 
        echo "<br><br><br>geblek lu keong<br>";
        $coousername='myCookie';
        $cooval=$url[0];
        //with referral
        $q=$pdo->query("SELECT COUNT(username) AS cu FROM t_un WHERE username='$cooval' AND status='1'");
        $f=$q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $cu=$f->cu;
        if($cu<>0){
            //right referral
            setcookie($coousername, $cooval, time() + (3600 * 24 * 365), "/"); // 1 year
        }else{
            //wrong referral
            if(!isset($_COOKIE[$coousername])){
                $cooval2='eagle';
                setcookie($coousername, $cooval2, time() + (3600 * 24 * 365), "/"); // 1 year
            }else{
                $q=$pdo->query("SELECT username FROM t_un WHERE status='1' AND ve='1' AND upgrade='1' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
                $f=$q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                $username=$f->username;
                setcookie($coousername, $username, time() + (3600 * 24 * 365), "/"); // 1 year
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
    exit;
?>
```

my .htaccess is just like this:

```
#Disallow viewing htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^/?$ /home [R=301,L]

#404 missing page
ErrorDocument 404 /pagenotfound.php
```

Now, I don't know where is the logic running, to the condition 1 or 2. Please anyone could help me cause I have been 3 days stack at here.

Comment: have you tried to observe your `$urlsave` ?

Comment: not only that, I want to know why does the echo "cooval=$cooval<br>"; always change, inconsistent result

Comment: i dont have an idea yet, but we need to know when this issue is happening. can you note multiple response ? `$urlexplode.' :: '. $urlsave`

Comment: it should be very simple, the logic should goes to the condition 1 and has not changed at all. But why doesn't like that, it doesn't make any sense, I'm really really really confused

Comment: ok, if thats the issue. i cant help, as i cant tracked down where it really happen..

Comment: Ok thank you @kiro112